# Asp.net + AngularJS with Razor rendering for authorization

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, razor, authorization, single-page-application

I want to create a SPA site using ASP.Net as backend and Angular as frontend framework. The problem that I´m facing now is, how to manage users/roles? specifically whats the best approach for View Authorization (Displaying different menu items depending on the Role).

I was thinking on relying on Razor for this, just for the view authorization (using 'User.IsInRole') doing stuff like:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
{
     <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="module">
           <ul class="menu">
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="mainContent">
             Hello, @User.Identity.Name !
         </div>
     </div>
}
```

I know this isn´t the most elegant solution, but what would be the best alternative?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement authenticate method in your authentication controller and use this module in your angular js side. See this below link

https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth

Which might be helpful

Comment: I think this is more oriented to Authentication, but I'm struggling to get Authorization, which is, how to change the UI based on the user role.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are either using angular `ui-router` or `ng-route`

I would say that take use of resolve function of each state, in that you could call an server to get the `User` object if it is login, on basis of response return from the server we'll set value of `authenticationSvc` service.

Basically `User` will be inside `authenticationSvc`, you can place role of user in it.

**Example**

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
  templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
  controller: "HomeController",
  resolve: {
    auth: ["$q", "authenticationSvc", function($q, authenticationSvc) {
      var userInfo = authenticationSvc.getUserInfo();

      if (userInfo) {
        return $q.when(userInfo);
      } else {
        return $q.reject({ authenticated: false });
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.userInfo = authenticationSvc.getUserInfo();
```

**Markup**

```
 <div id="sidebar">
    <div class="module" ng-if="userInfo.roles['Administrators']">
       <ul class="menu">
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="mainContent">
         Hello, @User.Identity.Name !
     </div>
 </div>
```

Also refer [**this link**](http://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-authentication-angular-applications/) will help you in implementation.

Comment: Thank!, While the example helps on how to secure routes, I think this is more oriented to Authentication, what I'm really struggling is to get Authorization, which is, how to change the UI based on the user role.

Comment: ya..i personally believe this the best way to use authorization..As i gave example for a single. You should call function on the resolve of each route..

Comment: @edua_glz did you get progress in this?